# Does GPU help a web developer?

Tags: laptop, gpu

As a web developer I plan to upgrade my current laptop. I rarely spend my time on video gaming. However I wonder does a powerful GPU help me in any other aspect of computing? A good GPU increases the laptop price considerably, make it heavier and noisier (as affect the cooling system) and decrease battery life.

So do you think I better off to buy a good laptop with the INTEL gpu, or a laptop with an average gpu or on the other hand a gaming laptop?

I spend most of my day on Phpstorm that is a really heavy IDE (java based). I don't develop graphic intensive projects.

Comment: The integrated GPU is more than enough for web dev. (With the possible exception of WebGL and WebVR but if you were doing that you'd know.)

Comment: It depends on what web projects you are working on. If you are doing HTML and CSS only, you definitelly don't need extra GPU, but if you are creating WebVR, WebCL or WebGL apps, then it may be good to have better GPU. Keep in mind that, in general, GPU is faster than CPU only in specific tasks (i.e. when the problem can be solved by simultaneously spawning multiple threads). GPU will not speed up your JavaScript.

Comment: I guess having two screens can help a programmer but that doesn't require a good GPU

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through the similar question. I'm not web development, but regularly work in management consulting, using phyton, MS office in general, browsing, and occasionally gaming. I was reluctant to buy an "integrated graphics" due to bad experiences in the past. After lots of research on the benchmarks and performances of the most recent integrated GPUs, i found that they are good enough for multiple monitors, high resolutions and even some light gaming. I ended up buying an i7 with an intel graphics 620 and it works extremely well, with 10h of battery and enough speed for what I need.

Especially if you value mobility, **I would even strongly recommend you to take an integrated GPU**, as it will increase your battery life without visible impact on your work.

You can read more about the integrated graphics [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/intel-hd-graphics-comparison).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider screen resolution which may be better with a gpu but also depends on the monitor.

For colours, there are many tools here but each set up can show the colours differently and I don't believe many sites respect the Web safe colors.

However a gpu I feel could have a bigger drain on battery life (if using a laptop).

There are exceptions to this of course but as you didn't mention any graphic intensive work in your post I'll assume it's not applicable.